# tcolorbox frame title inside the box

Tags: tcolorbox

[image]

I'm trying to clone the box shown in the image above.
But I'm having trouble to copy the style of the title box.
The title box is inside the box, but I don't know how to make it in the box.
How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newtcolorbox{opening}[1][]{
boxsep=1mm,
left=1mm,
sharp corners,
colback=green!15!white,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
colbacktitle=green!65!black, enhanced,
title=OPENING PROBLEM,
frame hidden,#1}
\newenvironment{thinkabout}{Things to think about:\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{opening}
The population of rodents on an island is currently $500$. Its graowth rate is expected to be given by $\dfrac{dP}{dt}=0.1P\left( 1-\dfrac{P}{3000} \right) $, where $t$ is the time in years from now. 

\begin{thinkabout}
\item How would we describe the relationship between the variables $P$ and $t$ ?
\item What would the graph of $P$ against $t$ look like?
\item How can we write $P$ as a function of $t$?
\item Can you find:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item the expected population after $8 $ years
    \item the expected time taken for the population to increase to $2000$
    \item the maximum population which the island can sustain?
\end{enumerate}
\end{thinkabout}
\end{opening}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hiding the frame, make it the same colour as your background and the title will look as if it is inside the box:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newtcolorbox{opening}[1][]{
boxsep=1mm,
left=1mm,
sharp corners,
colback=green!15!white,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
colbacktitle=green!65!black, enhanced,
title=OPENING PROBLEM,
colframe=green!15!white,
boxrule=5pt,titlerule=5pt,
,#1}
\newenvironment{thinkabout}{Things to think about:\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{opening}
The population of rodents on an island is currently $500$. Its graowth rate is expected to be given by $\dfrac{dP}{dt}=0.1P\left( 1-\dfrac{P}{3000} \right) $, where $t$ is the time in years from now. 

\begin{thinkabout}
\item How would we describe the relationship between the variables $P$ and $t$ ?
\item What would the graph of $P$ against $t$ look like?
\item How can we write $P$ as a function of $t$?
\item Can you find:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item the expected population after $8 $ years
    \item the expected time taken for the population to increase to $2000$
    \item the maximum population which the island can sustain?
\end{enumerate}
\end{thinkabout}
\end{opening}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tonyhuh You're welcome!